# How to rename duplicate xml elements with XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have been trying but no luck for the past few days. I have 2 duplicate elements (ELM.11) in my xml. I would like to rename the other as (ELM.12).  Please take a look at the input below. Thanks in advance.

```
INPUT
<ROOT>
    <ELM>
        <ELM.10>ABC</ELM.10>
        <ELM.11>001252016175000006</ELM.11>
        <ELM.11>3796124</ELM.11>
        <ELM.13>
            <TS.1>20160623134857-0400</TS.1>
        </ELM.13>
        <ELM.14>GLB</ELM.14>
        <ELM.15>F</ELM.15>
    <ELM>
</ROOT>

EXPECT OUTPUT
<ROOT>
    <ELM>
        <ELM.10>ABC</ELM.10>
        <ELM.11>001252016175000006</ELM.11>

        <ELM.12>3796124</ELM.12>

        <ELM.13>
            <TS.1>20160623134857-0400</TS.1>
        </ELM.13>
        <ELM.14>GLB</ELM.14>
        <ELM.15>F</ELM.15>
    <ELM>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: While I'm sure there are people here that would be happy to help you (maybe if you paid them), Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  You need to provide what you have actually tried to do so far (i.e. an [mcve])

Comment: It turns out to be one line of code I'm looking for.  I would never considered stackoverflow to be a code writing service.  Thanks for your 2-cent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little ambiguous. If I read it literally, the answer is very simple:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ELM.11[2]">
    <ELM.12>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ELM.12>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```